# Ruby syntax error for non existent lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

I'm getting `41: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end`. I also have the error for line 43.

The catch? My code stops at line 40, and I'm not seeing any extra spaces or tabs in Sublime text... What gives?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title">
      <h1>Listing reports</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Summoner Name</th>
                  <th>User</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% @reports.each do |report| %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= report.description %></td>
                    <td><%= report.user.email if report.user %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to 'Show', report %></td>
                    <% if report.user == current_user %>
                      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_report_path(report) %></td>
                      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', report, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <br>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <%= link_to 'New Report', new_report_path %>
            <% end %>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you're looking at is the code you're actually running? Try temporarily replacing the whole contents of the file with a test entry to make sure you're editing the file that's being looked at.

Comment: Looks like you're missing `end` for `each` block.  In fact it's the `if` inside `each` that's missing `end`.

Comment: @reports.each is missing an end. Add `<% end %>` to line 30ish

Comment: Oh, @vee already wrote that

Comment: Thanks guys! Adding the extra <% end %> fixed it ^_^ Thanks for bearing with me, only been coding about two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Ruby file. It looks like it is some templating language, possibly ERb. Obviously, Ruby doesn't understand ERb, Ruby only understands Ruby. Therefore, the file needs to be converted to Ruby first, and there's no guarantee that this converted file will have the exact same line numbers as the original template file.